# Computing a sum involving binomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, hypergeometric-function

I am doing some (pretty heavy) computations, and I am stuck at a point that can be rephrased as follows:

> Let $m>n\ge0$ be two integers. Compute
>
> $$\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{m-k}x^{n-k}.$$

I tried to proceed as follows: denote $a = m-n$. Then we have
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{m-k}x^{n-k} & = x^{-a}\int dx\ x^a\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}x^{n-k}\\
& = x^{-a}\int dx\ x^a(1+x)^n\\
& = \frac{{}_2F_1(a,-n,a+1,-x)}{a},
\end{align}
where the last step was gently provided by [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E-a%20Integate%20x%5E%7Ba-1%7D(1%2Bx)%5En%20dx). I am not familiar with hypergeometric functions at all, so I was wondering if there is any hope to express this in a simpler way (but still without invoking big sums or integrals), in particular considering that $n,a,m$ are integers.

Comment: You can express said hypergeometric function in terms of the Jacobi polynomials, but I think this just ends up being equivalent to your initial series.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure that would be helpful in what I'm trying to do. But thanks anyway for the input!